# Symfony2 - Include template from current bundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've not been able to find anything useful about this in the Twig or Symfony2 documentation, so thought I would ask here.

Does anybody know if it's possible to include a Twig template in Symfony2 relative to the current bundle, without specifying the name? Something along these lines:

`{% include .:Foo:bar.html.twig %}`

I'm just a bit fed up of having to enter the long, ugly bundle name when they're all in the same bundle. Also means if the bundle name ever changed for whatever reason, I'd have to find & replace every single include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in the days when I was using bundles, I came up with a quick solution that you could base upon:

```
{% set bundle = app.request.get('_template').get('bundle') %}
{% set controller = app.request.get('_template').get('controller') %}

{% include bundle ~ ':' ~ controller ~ ':foo.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I would move that into a function?

Comment: Depends on your needs. I just gave you the idea. ;)